# How to excute correct "sed" command in shelljs?

Tags: node.js, shell, command, shelljs

I am using shelljs to excute shell command to find and replace content in my configuration file.
My configuration is file content like bellow, I want to find all string "" by the name of my clinic (This is a parameter that i passed from the client like: var clinicName = req.body.clinicName;)

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  # core backend service
  core-backend:
    image: "vany/multi-tenant-core:latest"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.tenant==multi-tenant]
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
    labels:
      collectord.io/logs-eventpattern: '^\['
    environment:
      PORT: 5000
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
      DATABASE: 'mongodb://<tclinic-name>:yeuemdailau@10.117.134.9:27017/<tclinic-name>?authSource=<tclinic-name>'
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
#volumes:   
#  media-upload:
#    driver: lizardfs
```

If I using manual command like this, the result is correct.

```
sed -i "s/<tclinic-name>/hanoitclinic/g" clinic-api-core.yml
```

The result will be correct like this:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  # core backend service
  core-backend:
    image: "vany/multi-tenant-core:latest"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.tenant==multi-tenant]
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
    labels:
      collectord.io/logs-eventpattern: '^\['
    environment:
      PORT: 5000
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
      DATABASE: **'mongodb://hanoitclinic:yeuemdailau@10.117.134.9:27017//hanoitclinic?authSource=hanoitclinic'**
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
#volumes:   
#  media-upload:
#    driver: lizardfs
```

But if I using shelljs, the code like this (with clinicName = "hanoitclinic" that I pass from client

```
 var shell = require('shelljs');
shell.sed('-i', '<tclinic-name>', clinicName, "clinic-api-core.yml");
```

The result is not correct, it's only replace once:

```
 DATABASE: 'mongodb://hanoitclinic:yeuemdailau@10.117.134.9:27017/<tclinic-name>?authSource=<tclinic-name>'
```

Please take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to example in the ShellJS [documentation](http://documentup.com/shelljs/shelljs#sedoptions-search_regex-replacement-file--file-) - and [here](http://documentup.com/shelljs/shelljs#pipes) - for

```
sed([options,] search_regex, replacement, file [, file ...])
```

the `search_regex` can be a normal `replace()` regexp so I'd suggest
using the `g`lobal flag:

```
shell.sed('-i', /<tclinic-name>/g, clinicName, "aibolit-api-core.yml");
```

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood so I tried '/<tclinic-name>/g' but the correct is /<tclinic-name>/g. Thanks you